# Share UART via network

Tags: raspbian, networking, windows, uart

Is it possible to share the UART `/dev/ttyAMA0` of the Raspberry Pi via the local network so that it is accessible from a Windows Machine?

I think there will also be some driver for the Windows Machine necessary so that `/dev/ttyAMA0` is listed e.g. as `COM1` on the Windows PC.

I looked for some solution but I did not find one. May be you can help me.

Comment: Maybe not so it literally appears as COM1, but obviously yes you can transfer the data over the network, and I am certain there are applications kicking around for this that will work *from* a pi (because I've written one but haven't bothered to publish it because I noticed there's already stuff that does much the same thing).  As to whether they have corresponding Windows parts I dunno, but presumably.

Comment: Oh look: http://superuser.com/a/54727/257378 <- Found that by searching "UART over TCP".  It might not be quite what you are after though.  I'd focus on the windows side first because for sure it is easy enough to do a crude counterpart on the linux side (just read/write from the network to the UART).   However, wait a day and see if someone who's used the slightly fancier thing I was thinking of in my first comment comes along.  Pretty sure it was actually written with the Pi in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a solution based on this post: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/serial-over-lan-from-linux-to-windows-825334/#post4062960

Following steps are necessary.

- Install `com0com` and `com2tcp` on the Windows machine and `socat` on the Raspberry.
- Then add a virtual COM-pair (`COM0 <-> COM25`) on the Windows machine with the help of `com0com`.
- Execute following command on the Raspberry. `socat file:/dev/ttyAMA0,raw,echo=0,b115200 tcp-l:3016,fork&` (adjust the device `/dev/ttyAMA0`, baudrate `b115200` and port `3016` according your needs)
- Start `com2tcp` on the Windows PC with following command. `com2tcp --baud 115200 --ignore-dsr \\.\COM25 192.168.0.1 3016`
- Now you can communicate via `COM0` with the device attached to `/dev/ttyAMA0`

Comment: Please mark your answer as expected... if it answered your question :) Which it looks like it did. Thank you for sharing too!

Answer (score 1):

You could buy a USB to UART converter and access it remotely using [USB/IP](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/). You won't be able to export the built-in UART this way, since USB/IP only works with USB devices.

The advantage of this method is that you get complete control over the UART from the remote machine, including changing the baudrate and manipulating hardware flow control lines.

If all you need is to access the UART in a terminal emulator, simply connecting to your RPi via SSH and running `screen /dev/ttyAMA0 115200` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

My pigpio library lets you run a [Python script](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) on a Windows' box which can use a Pi's serial link (and the GPIO).

See http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#serial_open